# Update user inputs into C# Service-based Database (using textboxes, MonthCalendars and Comboboxes)

Tags: c#, database, database-design, combobox, monthcalendar

I am new to C# and this was my general idea for the C# form: user (who has the role of a *Technician*) would be able to view Service Requests stored in the table RequestHistory, and would be able to update the details of the request such as *Description* (typed in a **textbox**), select *service status* (**Combobox**) and make an input for the *date of completion* (where the user selects a date using **MonthCalendar**).

However, in the error codes the program states that
"*A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods*" and that *"the name "status", "description", "collect", "requestid" does not exist in the current context"* and I'm having some difficulties in understanding exactly where I went wrong.

This was how I programmed for the **Update Button**
(pls ignore some of the //comments in the middle, those were past codes made before editing to the current version)

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Technician objUpdate = new Technician(mthCalCompletionDate.SelectionEnd.Day, txtboxDescription.Text, cboServiceStatus.SelectedValue);
        MessageBox.Show(objUpdate.UpdateService());
    }
```

While this code is stored in a **class called 'Technician'**

```
using System;
```

```
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ASSIGNMENT
{
    //public class Technician
    public class Technician
    {
        private string username;
        private string password;
        private string role;
        private int requestid;
        private string description;
        private string status;
        private int collect;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCS"].ToString());

        public string Description { get => description; set => description = value; }
        public string Status { get => status; set => status = value; }
        public int Collect { get => collect; set => collect = value; }
    }


    //Method to update Service Requests

    public string UpdateService(string des, string stat, int dateCollect)
    {
      
        String UpdateStatus;

        description = des;
        status = stat;
        collect = dateCollect;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCS"].ToString());
        con.Open();

        //SqlCommand objectcmd = new Constructor(sqlQuery, connectionString)

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update RequestHistory set Collection_Date ='" +dateCollect+ "', Description = '" + des + "', Service_Status= '" +stat+ "'  where ServiceID = '" +requestid+ "' ", con);
        
        //Update Request Descriptions, Date and Status WHERE ServiceID = RequestID textbox
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateCollect", mthCalCompletionDate.SelectionEnd.Day);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtboxDescription.Text);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", cboServiceStatus.SelectedValue);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i != 0)
            UpdateStatus = "Request Updated!";
        else
            UpdateStatus = "Unable to Update.";
 
        con.Close();

        return UpdateStatus; //If successful update = i>0

            }
    }
```

This is my first assignment using the language C#, so please forgive me for any dumb questions I may ask. Any help is much appreciated